# Open Java Applet in a New Browser Window

Tags: java, javascript, html, browser, applet

I just started using SSHTerm to embed a terminal client in my website, but I would like to have the Applet open in a new window. Is there any way to do this from the Applet with parameters (so the window is the same size as the Applet)?

```
<applet width="640" height="480" archive="SSHTermApplet-signed.jar,SSHTermApplet-jdkbug-workaround-signed.jar,SSHTermApplet-jdk1.3.1-dependencies-signed.jar"
code="com.sshtools.sshterm.SshTermApplet" codebase="." style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1; padding-left: 4; padding-right: 4; padding-top: 1; padding-bottom: 1">
<param name="sshapps.connection.host" value="host.domain.com">
<param name="sshapps.connection.userName" value="root">
<param name="sshapps.connection.connectImmediately" value="true">
<param name="sshapps.connection.authenticationMethod" value="password">
</applet>
```

Comment: Why not just create a HTML link that opens in a new page: `<a href="yourpage.html" target="_new">My SSH Term Page</a>`?

Comment: Rather than open up in a full new tab/browser window, I just wanted a window "popup" that matched the Applet size, in this case 640x480

Comment: Launch it using free-floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and it is guaranteed a new window.